# EFI boot order always resets after a reboot

Tags: windows, boot, archlinux, uefi

I've recently set up a dual boot between Windows 10 and Arch. Unfortunately the Windows Boot Manager always boot first. I've already tried to change the sequence via efibootmgr -o but after I reboot it always resets it to to Windows boot manager booting first. Does anyone know a fix to this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a quirk of your UEFI implementation. The easiest way out of it is to replace ESP:/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI file to be your transient bootloader (i.e. GRUB2), as right now it's probably a Windows bootloader that UEFI sets as default one no matter what.